# GetPrivateProfileString Return String Variable not set

Tags: vba

Im using getPrivateProfileString to read from an API. Here I call the method and get a store number

```
Rec = String(255, 0)
NC = GetPrivateProfileString("ConfigInfo", "store", "", Rec, 255, "C:\MyPath")
```

Now when I debug Rec has no value

However when I use Rec in a message box it shows its value as expected.

Why is the variable Rec an empty variable instead of holding my store number as expected? Why does Rec's value seem to be as expected in a message box?

Comment: what is your degug statement? try `debug.print Rec(0, 0)`

Comment: 10, which is my expected output. However when I pause and hover it shows Rec =

Comment: blank is the default value you specified when the section-key not found.  Did you pause on show message or on NC = ...?